# Calculating the limit of a quotient with exponential functions using exponent rules

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to calculate the following limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{3\cdot2^n - 2\cdot3^n}{ 5\cdot2^n - 6\cdot3^n}.$$

Any way, back to our topic, according to my book and wolframalpha, the answer is $\frac 13$ but I don't know how to get there.

I tried to work things out with this expression using exponent rules but couldn't simplify it.

Waiting for your help and thanks in advance!

Comment: The logic is that you ought to learn how to use mathjax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: multiply denimnator and numerator by $$\frac{1}{3^n}$$ we get $$\frac{3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n-2}{5\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n-6}$$

Comment: Well, I know that (2/3)^n when n->infinity equals 0.
So that leaves me with -2/-6 which is equal to 1/3.
But shouldn't I develop it more step?
Is to ok to say that any number between 0-1 times infinity equals zero?